# How to mock a Context object

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I am trying to test a module which contains a context object as follows:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory $productImageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    \Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface $viewConfig,
    ProductRepository $productRepo
)
    {
    parent::__construct($context, $productImageFactory, $assetRepo, $viewConfig);
    $this->productRepo = $productRepo;
}
```

When I run my Unit Test it gives me this error message:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Error : Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\Context, none given, called in ...
```

How can I make a mock of this object or make this error fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can test your class like this:

```
public function testSomething() 
{
    $contextMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context::class)
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
    $productImageFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ImageFactory::class)
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
    $assetRepoMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository::class)
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
    $viewConfigMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\View\ConfigInterface::class)
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
    $productRepoMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::class)
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();

    $productImageMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Image::class)
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();

    //mock here any methods you need to mock

    $productImageFactoryMock->method('create')->willReturn($productImageMock); 

    $model = new \The\Class\You\Want\To\Test( 
               $contextMock,
               $productImageFactoryMock,
               $assetRepoMock,
               $viewConfigMock,
               $productRepoMock
    ); 
    //do asserts here
}
```

You can move all the mock building to the `setUp()` method if you need to do more than 1 test.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! but I can not still mock the getSku() as you have mentioned in the code. so I post it here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122785/how-to-mock-an-external-resource-in-magento-2 may you please do me a favor to answer that too? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The following code will create a mock of the context in your test.

```
    $contextMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
```

From: `vendor/magento/module-sales/Test/Unit/Helper/DataTest.php:setup()`

You then will need to use the pass the `$contextMock` via the the object manager:

```
$objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);

$objectToTest = $objectManager->getObject(
        \Magento\Class\To\Test::class, [
            'context' => $contextMock,
            ...
        ]
    );
```

Or you can use a Mock and pass the argument if you need need to change the method output of the class you are changing:

```
$objectToTest = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Class\To\Test::class)
    ->setConstructorArgs([
        'context' => $contextMock
    ])->getMock();
```