# How to mock an external resource in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests, phpunit, mocks

I want to write unit test for a module which contains these functions:

```
public function abc($Str)
{
    $n = $this->def();
 ...
    return x;
}
public function def()
    {
 ...
        $productRepo= $this->productRepo->get($this->_product->getSku());
...
            return $something;
        }
```

I have alredy tried to mock a product and pass the sku value of it but every time it gives me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getSku() on a non-object in...
```

Here is how I wrote mock for it:

```
$sku->method('getSku')->willReturn('sku-test');
```

I have also tried to mock it this way in my setUp() but still getting the error:

```
    protected function setUp()
{

    $sku = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class)
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();
    $skuManager = $this->getMockBuilder(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface::class)
        ->setMethods(['getSku'])
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the mock to a local variable `$skuManager` and then do nothing with it.

When instantiating your component under test, you have to pass the mock as constructor parameter in place of the real `ProductRepository`.

Note that you should not use the ObjectManager **in unit tests** to instantiate your component. Create or mock the dependencies explicitly instead.