# Magento EE 2.1 : error of parameter type in Unit Test

Tags: magento-2.1, testing, unit-tests, phpunit

Using [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122426/how-to-mock-a-context-object) post, I tried my first Unit Test. The goal is to test a repository. However, despite mocking all required dependancies of the repository, I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Mybusiness\Retailers\Model\AssignmentRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Mybusiness\Retailers\Model\ResourceModel\Assignment, instance of Mock_Assignment_5b102d69 given, called in /var/www/testEric/mybusiness/mybusiness/app/code/Mybusiness/Retailers/Test/Unit/AssignmentRepositoryTest.php on line 23 and defined in /var/www/testEric/mybusiness/mybusiness/app/code/Mybusiness/Retailers/Model/AssignmentRepository.php:54
```

Here is my Test class:

```
<?php
namespace MyBusiness\Retailers\Test\Unit;

use MyBusiness\Retailers\Model\AssignmentRepository;

class AssignmentRepositoryTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private $assignmentRepository;

    public function __construct() {
        $resourceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(MyBusiness\Retailers\Model\ResourceModel\Assignment::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $assignmentInterfaceFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(MyBusiness\Retailers\Api\Data\AssignmentInterfaceFactory::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $assignmentCollectionFactoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder(MyBusiness\Retailers\Model\ResourceModel\Assignment\CollectionFactory::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->assignmentRepository = new AssignmentRepository(
            $resourceMock,
            $assignmentInterfaceFactoryMock,
            $assignmentCollectionFactoryMock
        );

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function testGetById() {
        $id = 4731;
        $retailer = 1;
        $zipcode = 13001;
        $city = "MARSEILLE - 13001";

        $theAssignment = $this->assignmentRepository->getById($id);

        $this->assertEquals($retailer, $theAssignment->getRetailer());
        $this->assertEquals($zipcode, $theAssignment->getZipCode());
        $this->assertEquals($city, $theAssignment->getCity());
    }
```

**EDIT**:

I tried the second part of the linked answer, and now, the message is different:

```
...does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments in /var/www/testEric/mybusiness/mybusiness/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php:246
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resourceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(MyBusiness\Retailers\Model\ResourceModel\Assignment::class)
```

You are not using a fully qualified class name here. That means, this gives you a mock object for the **nonexistent class**<sup>1</sup> `MyBusiness\Retailers\Test\Unit\MyBusiness\Retailers\Model\ResourceModel\Assignment` (the class name is "relative" to the current namespace)

**Solution:** change the line to

```
$resourceMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\MyBusiness\Retailers\Model\ResourceModel\Assignment::class)
```

(same for the other class names)

---

<sup>1) yes that is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125444/phpunit-mock-non-existing-classes</sup>